# C++ copy a part of a char array to another char array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy only a portion of a string (or char *) into another string (or another char *)

```
char * first_string = "Every morning I"
char * second_string = "go to the library, eat breakfast, swim."
char * final_string;
```

I would like to copy **part** of the second_string into the first_string.

For Example:

*Every morning I eat breakfast.*

What is the function that allows you to copy only a portion of a string, starting from a specific point in the string?

**Note:** I don't want to use string variables, but char *, or even char arrays, if possible.

Comment: `I don't want to use string variables, but char *, or even char arrays, if possible.` Why?

Comment: These should all be `char const*`, btw. If your compiler isn't already warning you about that then you are not using the proper flags.

Comment: I have bad memories with strings. I remember not being able to use strings in a win32 C++ file even after including the string header (<string.h>), so I try to avoid using them now. I'm still generally new to C++, so I use what I know how to use.

Comment: No, `string`s are way easier, here you will have to dynamically resize your buffer to copy the data, this is done automatically with `string`

Comment: @JamesDiaz that's because you don't include `<string.h>`, but `<string>`.

Comment: @JamesDiaz: `<string.h>` has not been "the string header" since the mid-1990s, i.e. before C++ was even internationally standardised as a language. Strings are _vastly_ and _disproportionately_ easier, and if you were having trouble with them then you should focus on fixing those problems rather than creating myriad new ones for yourself.

Comment: James, since you mentioned you're generally new to C++, if Luchian Grigore is right, it's important to point out that every standard library file in C++ will never have a header extension. So whenever you `#include` a standard library file and you're using C++ (in contrast to C) you should make sure there is **NO** `.h` at the end. (The proper way to `#include` a C library to C++ is with `c` in front of it. so `#include <math.h>` (which belongs to C) becomes `#include <cmath>`. And just a note: do use std::strings. if they don't work make sure that A) you've included it B) you're using `std`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to, use strcat (if you don't use strings, you should be ok with the C-functions anyway):

```
const char * first_string = "Every morning I";
const char * second_string = "go to the library, eat breakfast, swim.";
char final_string[80]; // make sure it's big enough - I haven't counted ;-)

strcpy(final_string, first_string);     // copy to destination
strcat(final_string, second_string+18); // append part of the second string
```

Comment: But that gives you `Every morning I eat breakfast, swim.` You want `strncat`, not `strcat`

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the swimming. However you have to add the dot at the end yourself...

Answer (score 7):

It's `std::copy`, but with your code it would result in undefined behavior, because you have pointers to string literals, which are illegal to modify.

You'll need something like

```
char first_string[256] = "Every morning I";
char second_string[256] = "go to the library, eat breakfast, swim.";

std::copy(
    &second_string[23],
    &second_string[36],
    &first_string[strlen(first_string)]
);
```

Indices might be off.

Comment: there's an analogy here somewhere about worms and being early?!

Comment: Your answer is totally right, but the person after you actually gave the me the function/and example I was looking for. If I could I would accept both answers, as both have helped me an equal amount.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use 'strncat()' like this:

```
const char * first_string = "Every morning I";
const char * second_string = "go to the library, eat breakfast, swim.";

char final_string [200];

//Copies first string first
strcpy(final_string, first_string);

//Copies second string
strncat(final_string, second_string[ text_position ], text_length);
```

Replace `text_position` with the position of `second_string` from which you may want to start copying text and replace `text_length` with the length of the portion of text you want to copy.

This way you may copy separate portions of text and not necessarily from a point of the string to the end.

Answer (score 1):

you could use strtok with "," as a delimiter to separate the parts of the second string and then use strcat to append that part onto the first string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strstr()` to search for the begining of the part you want, then `strcat()` to concatenate.

```
char * first_string = "Every morning I";
char * second_string = "go to the library, eat breakfast, swim.";
char * final_string;

char* s = "eat";
char* r = strstr(second_string, s);

strcat(final_string, first_string);
strcat(final_string, " ");
strcat(final_string, r);
```